# Convolution theorem on a non-abelian Lie group

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\mathrm{G}$ be a compact (simple, if it helps) non-abelian Lie group and let $\hat{\mathrm{G}}$ be its unitary dual of (equivalence classes) of irreducible unitary representations. Defining the Fourier transform by
$$ \hat{f}(\pi) = \int_{\mathrm{G}} f(x) \pi(x^{-1}) \, \mathrm{d} \mu(x),$$
where $\mu$ is a normalized Haar measure on $\mathrm{G}$, the Peter--Weyl theorem says that for $f \in L^2(\mathrm{G})$ one has the Fourier series expansion
$$ f(x) = \sum_{\pi \in \hat{\mathrm{G}}} d_\pi \operatorname{Tr}(\hat{f}(\pi) \pi(x)), $$
where $d_\pi$ is the dimension of $\pi$. Furthermore, if we define the convolution product $*$ by
$$ (f* g)(x) = \int_{\mathrm{G}} f(y) g(x y^{-1}) \, \mathrm{d} \mu(y), $$
then a version of the convolution theorem holds, namely that
$$ (\widehat{f * g})(\pi) = \hat{f}(\pi) \hat{g}(\pi). $$
**Question.** I am interested in whether there is a sense in which an ``inverse" convolution theorem might hold, something along the lines of 
$$ (\hat{f} * \hat{g})(\pi) = (\widehat{fg})(\pi). $$
**Edit.** On reflection this might be asking for a somewhat unnatural identity. Perhaps a more natural question to ask would be whether there exists a convolution product on $\hat{\mathrm{G}}$ that makes a similar identity hold?

If it helps, I am more specifically interested in the case when $\mathrm{G} = \mathrm{SU}(2)$. I am fairly new to this so would appreciate any pointers to standard references if this is quite well-known!

Comment: What would the convolution *mean* on the dual side?  (Maybe this is part of your question.)  There's a measure on that side (the Plancherel measure), but the lack of algebraic structure means that I have a hard time guessing how convolution should behave.

Comment: By the way, the Fourier transform of a character is a delta distribution, so I guess that uniquely pins down what convolution *must* be if it is to satisfy your desired identity.

Comment: @LSpice That's exactly what I would like to know. I wouldn't mind a result in terms of sums over irreducible representations, either. Perhaps there's a naturally defined convolution product on $\hat{\mathrm{G}}$?

Comment: In order to define a convolution it is enough to have a **hypergroup** structure (so that the "product" of two points is a measure). In your setup such a structure is provided by the decomposition of tensor products of irreducible representations.

Comment: I forget the precise conditions needed on the group, but when $G$ is unimodular there is an old paper of Stinespring that discusses an abstract approach to defining "dual convolution" in the sense that you describe. When $G$ is a compact group this is more or less what @RW describes (although you need to know more than merely the isomorphism classes if the irreducible constituents, you need the actual intertwining maps). For a semi-explicit formula for what happens when G is the real Heisenberg group, see Section 5 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.6403

Comment: @RW if $f$ and $g$ are not class functions then I think one needs a bit more than just the hypergroup structure (of course when they are class functions then you are just getting the hypergroup on ${\bf N}_0$ given by the usual Clebsch-Gordan rules). For general (smooth) functions on SU(2) we have a kind of operator-valued hypergroup, I think

Comment: To the OP: if you are just starting out, and you are interested mainly in SU(2) for now, then a good way to gain intuition for what this dual convolution looks like is to take an $f$ for which you know its non-abelian Fourier coefficients, and consider the Fourier coefficients of $f^n$ (pointwise product of functions). For $f(p) = {\rm Tr}(p)$ this basically ends up as the problem of writing powers of cosine in terms of cosines of various frequencies, a.k.a. Chebyshev polynomials

Comment: At least figuratively, "pointwise multiplication" _is_ "tensor product". The point is that "tensor products" maybe have more apparent structural properties than pointwise multiplication, so may suggest what features you'd want/require...

Comment: @paulgarrett True, but (as you know!) tensoring irreps doesn't usually give an irrep, and so defining the dual convolution in terms of the Fourier coefficients  (as one defines convolution of two functions in terms of the function values) is going to be tricky